# Adsense conflict on some pages

Tags: jquery, css, conflict, adsense

I have place adsense on my website, same ad code is working on all pages, accept two pages, Same ad code is included in header file but when I open a specific page it doesn't show adsense nor any error. Below are two pages

Adsense showing perfect at http://www.zikraynabi.com/
same ad code is not showing in internal page. 
http://www.zikraynabi.com/Muslim-boys-and-girls-Names-List.php

Please let me know if any jquery or css could cause of conflict.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this error on the names list page:

```
<div><span>Can&#039;t Load URL: The domain of this URL isn&#039;t included in the app&#039;s domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.</span><script>if (typeof console !=="undefined" && console.log) console.log("Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.");</script></div>
```

Part of the error states: "Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains". [I went to Adsense instructions here and found you need to make sure you call your url without www or you will only serve ads to your home page](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/2781214?hl=en#format).

Once you remove "www" from Adsense for the site, it should work.

Comment: thank you so much. I have fixed url on entire site to non www url because in adsense my website was verified with non wwww. Thanks once again :)

Comment: Good! Glad that worked for you @TechBoy

Comment: thank you so much. It is working here is the proof. 
http://zikraynabi.com/Muslim-boys-and-girls-Names-List.php